# Match starting characters of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have string like:

```
/transaction/tran_id=123
```

I want to match `/transaction/` part of the string. if it's so then,

```
window.location.href = url;
```

else

```
alert("Not URL");
```

I tried with `str.match("^string")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( url.indexOf('/transaction/') === 0 )
    window.location.href = url;
```

You don't need a regex, just use indexOf, if the index is zero, the url starts with that string

Answer (score 0):

**/^/\w/$/.test(str)** tell can tell you if your string contain /anyword/, which will be more general. Hope it can help you.